# Adding user input into equation through a variable possible? (C#)

Tags: c#, variables

I apologize if this is a really simple solution...

So I'm trying to get an Ending Balance from 4 inputs, those being

- Starting Balance
- Number of months that have elapsed
- User Specified yearly interest rate
- and a optional monthly contribution that the user can put in. This is what I would imagine the equation to be

```
balance = contribution + balance + (INTEREST_RATE * balance) + (yearly * balance);
```

Everything is fine until the compiler states that Use of unassigned local variable 'contribution' This really confuses me because at the comment at the top of the code I have stated that contribution will be an int.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void calculateButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Constant for the monthly interest rate.
        const decimal INTEREST_RATE = 0.005m;

        // Local variables
        decimal balance; // The account balance
        int months; // The number of months
        int contribution;
        int count = 1; // Loop counter, initialized with 1
        decimal yearly;

        // Get the starting balance.
        if (decimal.TryParse(txtStartBalance.Text, out balance))
        {
            // Get the number of months.
            if (int.TryParse(txtMonths.Text, out months))
            {
                // Get the yearly interest rate
                if (decimal.TryParse(txtYearly.Text, out yearly))
                {
                    //Get monthly contribution
                    if (int.TryParse (txtMonthly.Text, out contribution));
                }
                // The following loop calculates the ending balance.
                while (count <= months)
                {
                    // Add this month's interest to the balance.
                    balance = contribution + balance + (INTEREST_RATE * balance) + (yearly * balance);

                    // Display this month's ending balance.
                    if (rdoEnglish.Checked == false)
                        lstDetails.Items.Add("ʻO ka pale hope " + "no ka mahina " + count + " ʻO " + balance.ToString("c"));
                    else
                        lstDetails.Items.Add("The ending balance for " + "month " + count + " is " + balance.ToString("c"));

                    // Add one to the loop counter.
                    count = count + 1;
                }

                // Display the ending balance.
                txtEnding.Text = balance.ToString("c");
```

Again thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Consider the paths taken through the code that leads to the line that gives the error, and see if there is one that does not assign a value to `contribution`. What if the value in either `txtYearly.Text` or `txtMonthly.Text` does not successfully parse as a decimal or int (respectively)? If that happens, and `count <= months` is still true, then you skip the assignment of `contribution`, and then try to use it.

Comment: @St.Pat `contribution` will be set to 0 if `txtMonthly.Text` fails to parse, since `out` parameters must be assigned. The problem is just with `txtYearly.Text`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This really confuses me because at the comment at the top of the code I have stated that contribution will be an int.

Yes but you have not assigned a *value* to the variable in at least one path your code can take. (Specifically if `int.TryParse (txtMonthly.Text, out contribution));` fails) And then you try to use `contribution` in the line:

```
balance = contribution + balance + (INTEREST_RATE * balance) + (yearly * balance);
```

You need to assign a value to `contribution` before you use it. Think about what `contribution` is supposed to represent and assign it to a value accordingly

Comment: I think I get it? In the lines above where I state all my variables I tried to assign
            int contribution = int.TryParse (txtMonthly.Text);
but I get an error about tryParse taking 1 argument.

Comment: @BrandonLau Yes that is because `tryParse` takes two arguments. If you are only trying to pass only one argument you could use `int contribution = int.Parse(txtMonthly.Text);`

Comment: @BrandonLau I would rework your code to handle if any of your parses fail

Comment: Awww jeez, I feel so dumb. I had the solution up a long time ago. It gave me a incorrect string format error. I should've put that into my question but I disregarded it. I think that happened because when I tried to only calculate the starting balance and months only (without putting in a number for contribution in the box) it just closed the window and brought me to the exception. I had to make an "else" error message to prevent it from crashing. As you can tell I'm EXTREMELY new to this...

Comment: so yes int contribution = int.Parse(txtMonthly.Text); IS the solution as GBlodgett said.

Answer (score 0):

Try to declare your variables Like below:

```
decimal.TryParse(txtStartBalance.Text, out decimal balance);
```

it is better to make a checkbox for the contribution field (`txtMonthly`) and set its visibility to `Checkbox.checked` property so if the user wants to set the optional contribution value, has to check the checkbox to write it down.
Also using that `if`s in your code is useless until you throw `Exceptions` when those `TryParse` methods retrun false and warn the user to try again with right inputs.

Comment: Duly noted! Your checkbox idea is actually what helped me achieve Eureka!!! Thank you! Now I just have to find out how to code that error message in...

Comment: @BrandonLau simply you can control the flow of your code with `else` statement so if the `TryParse` returned false use `messagebox.show(…)` to warn the user and your app does not evaluate the balance and clears the textboxes.